# Is there a way to override the Copy on Write behavior for Swift arrays?

Tags: swift

I'm working on a project where I need to work with large arrays, and by using UnsafeMutablePointers, I get a threefold speed increase over using the regular array methods. However, I believe the copy on write behavior is causing me to change instances that I do not want to be affected. For example, in the following code, I want to update the values in copyArray, but leave the original values in anArray.

```
import Foundation

func increaseWithPointers(_ arr: inout [Int]) {
    let count = arr.count
    let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: &arr)
    for i in 0..<count {
        ptr[i] = ptr[i] + 1
    }
}

var anArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
var copyArray = anArray

increaseWithPointers(&copyArray)
print(anArray)
```

Executing this code prints [2,3,4,5,6].

I can get around this by declaring copyArray as follows:

```
var copyArray = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 5)
for i in 0..<5 {
    copyArray[i] = anArray[i]
}
```

However, this requires writing each value twice: to zero, then to the intended value. Is there a way to efficiently guarantee a copy of an array?

Comment: Isn't the reason for the speedup with `UnsafeMutablePointer` that it is *not* doing the copy on write? In other words you've "overridden the copy on write behavior for Swift arrays" by using the `UnsafeMutablePointer`. If you want copy on write, simply remove the `UnsafeMutablePointer` and do the work on the provided `inout [Int]`. Or just do `anArray.map { $0 + 1 }`

Comment: Interesting. I ran your code and got `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as the output.

Comment: In the actual code, the operations being performed on the array are more extensive, which is why I need the speed boost from using pointers. However, I need the operations to be limited to the context of the copy.

Comment: Like @MartinR I also get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: It's not clear how using pointers here could be faster while maintaining value semantics. The cost is going to be making the copy. If you avoid making copies, then you're going to share state. If you do make copies, then you're going to spend time doing the copy. I don't see how this can be resolved using a strict type like Array (lazy types like a lens can avoid copying of course, but they have different performance trade-offs). This doesn't seem like a Swift issue; it would apply to any language with strict collections, right?

Comment: The question here is, if you "guarantee a copy of an array," isn't that *precisely* the performance cost you're trying to avoid? It's not clear why the complexity of the operations being performed would have any impact. The cost is a single copy in any case, right? Are you passing this array around to lots of different operations and each is forcing a copy perhaps (because it can't prove it has the only reference?)

Comment: What I'm looking for is a copy of an array where each value is written once, rather than being written with zeroes and then the value. This, however, does seem to be a bug in Swift 4, as the above code works in Swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem using Xcode 9 beta 3, but not using Xcode 8.3.3. I suggest you file a [Swift bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/).

This fixes the problem:

```
import Foundation

func increaseWithPointers(_ arr: inout [Int]) {
    arr.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (buffer) in
        for i in buffer.indices {
            buffer[i] += 1
        }
    }
}

var anArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
var copyArray = anArray

increaseWithPointers(&copyArray)
print(anArray)
```

Comment: You are right, Xcode 9b3 behaves differently. I wonder if `let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: &arr)` is "allowed" at all, as it creates a pointer to the element storage which may become invalid.

Comment: Agreed; the original use of `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(mutating:)` is undefined behavior. There's no promise that it points to anything in particular (or even to valid memory). The use of `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` here is required (though doesn't promise the performance desired).

Comment: Awesome, and thanks. I'll file a report. It does seem to be a Swift 4 issue.